# How to get a user-input string as an array of individual characters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, character

I want the user to input a string and then each character of that string gets assigned to an element in an array.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Apples {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = userInput.nextLine();

        int arrayLength = name.length();

        String ArrayName[] = new String [arrayLength];

        for(int counter = 0; counter < arrayLength; counter++){

            ArrayName[counter] = name.substring(counter);


            System.out.println("Element No" + counter + ": " + name.substring(counter));

        }



    }
```

Comment: Just use `userInput.toCharArray()`.

Comment: Use [`String.charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) instead of `substring`.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = userInput.nextLine();

        int arrayLength = name.length();

        String ArrayName[] = new String [arrayLength];
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

        for(int counter = 0; counter < arrayLength; counter++) {
            ArrayName[counter] = chars[counter] + "";
            System.out.println("Element No" + counter + ": " + name.substring(counter));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for introducing me to char array... as i havent come across it yet, but your code still doesnt assign individual characters to an element of the array... unless i ran it wrong

Comment: ignore my last comment... you were right... i hadnt changed my syso to print out the char array

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apples {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = userInput.nextLine();

    int arrayLength = name.length();
    int temp = 1;
    String ArrayName[] = new String [arrayLength];

    for(int counter = 0; counter < arrayLength; counter++){

        ArrayName[counter] = name.substring(counter, name.length()-name.length()+temp);// HAD TO ADD THIS TO GET IT WORKING
        temp++;

System.out.println("Element No" + counter + ": " + ArrayName[counter]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the String's [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method. If you call this method on a String, it will return an array of `chars` exactly as you needed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apples {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = userInput.nextLine();
    char[] nameArray = name.toCharArray();

    for(int counter = 0; counter < nameArray.length; counter++){
        System.out.println("Element No" + counter + ": " + nameArray[counter]);
    }
  }
}
```

Check the documentation linked above to see a full explanation of how it works as well as other methods you can call on a String object.